# Group Permissions in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, pnp-powershell

I have SP 2013 sites. I want to read the group on `user.aspx` page with permission level. But I am getting error on get permission. some one help me with this.

```
$SiteGroups = Get-PnPGroup 
 
Write-host "Total Number of Groups Found:"$SiteGroups.Count

ForEach($Group in $SiteGroups)
{
    $GName = $Group.Title
    $GID = $Group.Id

    $Role = Get-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $Group.Title #I am getting error here
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error message? Do you have site collection administrator or site owner permissions?

Comment: yes i am SCA of the site

Comment: I have attached that error message, you can see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the below powershell script as an admin:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$SPSiteUrl = Read-Host "Enter the Url of the Site Collection"
$SPSite = Get-SPSite $SPSiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
if($SPSite -ne $null){

    $SPWebCollection = $SPSite.AllWebs

    foreach($SPWeb in $SPWebCollection){

        Write-Output "Site Title:" $SPWeb.Title "contains the following groups"
        Write-Output "======================================================"

        foreach($SPGroup in $SPWeb.Groups){
 
            Write-Output $SPGroup.Name
            Write-Output $SPGroup.ID
            Write-Output " "

        }
    }
}

else{

    Write-Host "Requested Site Could Not be found" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
}
```

[image]

[image]

======================== **Update Answer** =======================

Please run the below powershell script as an admin:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

$sites = get-spsite "http://sp/sites/echo/"

foreach ($site in $sites)
{

    write-host -foregroundcolor Green "Working on Site Collection: "$site.RootWeb.Title "..."
    write-host ""

    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
        {
            $GroupName = $roleAssignment.Member.Name
           
            foreach($spgroup in $web.Groups)
            {
                if($spgroup.Name -eq $GroupName)
                {

                    write-host -foregroundcolor White "Group Name: "$GroupName "......"

                    foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                    {

                        write-host -foregroundcolor Yellow "Permission Level: "$roleDefinition.Name "..."

                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

       $web.Dispose()

}
```

[image]

======================== `Updated Answer` =======================

Here are two related articles that may help you.

- [Get Web Groups With Permissions Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-web-groups-with-permissions-using-csom1)
- [CSOM to retrieve Permission Levels for a Group?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d14eef00-17eb-466f-b786-6f2eb5fe6db3/csom-to-retrieve-permission-levels-for-a-group?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: Thanks for your code. But we are not using server side. Also, i can read the group, But group permission not able to get it.

Comment: I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: thanks @EchoDu_MSFT But i am looking for the code with pnp powershell, server side is not supporting in our environment. we dont have sharepoint farm in or server. if u help me with client side code that could be great. I have posted my code where i am getting the error. pls check it

Comment: Hi Liz. The "Get-PnPGroupPermissions" command is applicable to SharePoint Online, not to SharePoint Server. Therefore, we cannot achieve your needs through the pnp command.

Comment: okk thanks, then any CSOM Command is available

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for this links it is working